# iOS use couchbase lite

Tags: ios, objective-c, couchbase-lite

i want to make a function make  server database and app database sync each other. just like we commit and sync codes to github. Is the couchbase lite can do that? if it can not, what framework can ? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, Couchbase Lite on a mobile device can sync to Couchbase Server via Sync Gateway.  No additional framework is needed, it's all built in.